# I can't find the right way to reference "Parent"

Tags: vba, ms-access, parent

On my Access main form I have a list box control (named "ActionsTaken") that shows a list of actions taken that are associated with the main form record.  These are kept in a separate table linked to the main table.  With a button I open a subform to add items to the list.  After typing in the text I press a "Done" button which closes the subform with a macro.  When the subform closes the deactivate event triggers an event procedure that validates the data, writes it to the Actions Table, and (hopefully) requeries the list control on the main form.  Everything works if I use an explicit reference to the control on the main form for the requery, But this subform is called from several different main forms, so I want to refer to the control on the main form using "Parent."  The syntax I think should work is:

```
Me.Parent!ActionsTaken.Requery
```

When the code executes I get a debug interrupt on the above line, and when I reset the code execution I get a pop up box with "There is no field named 'Me.Parent!ActionsTaken' in the current record."  The control is definitely there (remember, an explicit reference to it works).

I suspect I don't understand how "Parent" should be referenced.  I've found many other syntaxes with various combinations of dot and bang, and with the "Me" left off.  Some give me different error messages, but none work.

I've found a few awkward work-arounds, but I'm really curious as to what's wrong.

Comment: What you have looks correct. It should work. I would on the main from in design mode click on the list box, and look at the properties sheet - check and double check the name of the control.You could try/use me.Parent.ActionsTaken.Requery, but my bets are that  the list box has some name like list20 or some such. The list box certainly does not necessary have the same name as the column it may well be bound to.

Comment: What do you mean by 'opens the subform'? You are opening an independent form therefore it is not a subform and does not have a parent.

Comment: Albert - The box name is correct.  I think June 7 may have found the problem.

Comment: Well, if it not actually a sub form, then me.parent means nothing at all. If this is actually a separate form being launched, then it not a sub form, and has zero to do with  subform and is not called as such. If you are launching a separate form, then in the forms on-load  event, simply grab screen.ActiveForm into a varible. You can then go MyPrevous.SomeControl.Requery. Define the var as a type form, and define it at the  forms code level.

Comment: I find [this](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)  site useful for remembering how to reference forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subform is a form sitting on another form (this is the 'parent') and opens when that other form (the 'parent') is opened and therefore is not a subform and does not have a parent.

Pass form name to second opened form via OpenArgs:
`DoCmd.OpenArgs "secondformname", , , , , , Me.Name`

Then the second form can reference the first:
`Forms(Me.OpenArgs).ActionsTaken.Requery`

Another approach is to open second form with acDialog which will suspend first form code execution until second form closes.

```
DoCmd.OpenArgs "secondformname", , , , , acDialog
Me.ActionsTaken.Requery
```

Comment: June - Thanks, what you are saying makes a lot of sense.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: June:  I have it working thanks to you.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, thanks to June and others.  I bound the "Child" form to a table even though it's not needed as this lets me indirectly pass the record number (ID) via the OpenForm command.  I pass the "Parent" form name to the "Child" (Add New Action subform) with the OpenArgs argument of the OpenForm command:

```
strFormName = Me.Name
DoCmd.OpenForm "Add New Action subform", , _
    "Comment Card ID Query", "[Comment Card].ID=[ID]" _
    , , , Me.Name
```

When I am done with the "Child" I execute the following code:

```
Dim strParentName As String
strParentName = Me.OpenArgs

' Requery the Actions List Box on the Parent
[Forms](strParentName)!ActionsTaken.Requery

' Close the form
DoCmd.Close
```

I tried June's suggested syntax: Forms(Me.OpenArgs....) but I got errors from Access in Office 365.  Using a string variable worked.

Thanks for all the help!